# Writing multiple output file matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io

I want to write output of code periodically in different files in some specific folder.
Code I am using is as follows:

```
for i=1:m
% some other things
     if (mod(i,1000)==0)
      y=[1:dx:n_x;c_initial.'];
      fn = ['/home/alekhine' num2str(i) '.dat'];
     fid=fopen(fn);
      fprintf(fid,'%6.4f  %12.8f\n',y);

      fclose(fid);
      end
end
```

But I am getting error from Matlab as follows

```
Error using ==> fprintf
Invalid file identifier.  Use fopen to generate a valid file
identifier.
```

. What is wrong in the code? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You seem to be missing a path separator after `/home/alekhine`.

Comment: @mathematician1975, thanks for the instruction. posted the error.

Comment: @Thor, Thanks a lot, path was set properly...!!. If you post your comment as answer i can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing a path separator in the path generation:

```
fn = ['/home/alekhine' num2str(i) '.dat'];
```

Should be:

```
fn = ['/home/alekhine/' num2str(i) '.dat'];
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't give the `permission` argument to the fopen function, so it is opened for reading only.

See the docs (http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fopen.html) for valid values for `permission`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Warren for the reply. It seems that I was not setting the path correctly. reference you gave will be useful for future purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Just FYI, the preferred way of constructing filenames is to use [FULLFILE](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/fullfile.html). In this case, you could do

```
fn = fullfile('/home/alekhine', [num2str(i), '.dat']);
```

FULLFILE is preferred because it understands the different file separators on different OS types (i.e. `\` on Windows and `/` on UNIX/Mac).